# Mule - Error queue retry to queue

Tags: queue, jms, mule, try-catch, activemq-classic

I use a `JMS component (ActiveMQ)` in my `mule flow`:

`HTTP Listener` -> `Payload` -> `JMS (/NormalQueue)` -> `XSLT` -> `WS Consumer`

I have a `catch-exception strategy` in that flow and it has a JMS that store the message failed `(/ErrorQueue)`.

I want to do a **stopped flow** by default that the `/ErrorQueue` pass to `/NormalQueue` with a Groovy Script.

I don't want to use the Rollback because I need the message.

How can I pass the messages between that queues? Or what is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this is likely outside of your current flow. Why not make an additional, simple flow called something like `JMSResubmit` that is two simple nodes with no need for a Groovy script:

`JMS Input /ErrorQueue` --> `JMS Output /NormalQueue`

Now anytime anything is put onto the `/ErrorQueue`, it is sent back to the `/NormalQueue`